# React Django WebSocket connection challenge

Tags: reactjs, django, websocket, django-channels

The challenge I am facing is in trying to connect my Django backend with React frontend app.
The error that I am getting is:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/week/' failed: _callee$ @ Week.jsx:77
```

Here is the Week.jsx code:

```
export default function Week(props) {
  const [scoops, setScoops] = useState([]);
  const ws = useRef(null);

  useEffect(async () => {
    ws.current = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws/week/");
    ws.current.onopen = () => console.log("ws opened");
    const res = await fetch("/api/scoops/week/");
    const data = await res.json();
    setScoops(data);
  }, []);

  const rows = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < scoops.length; i++) {
    rows.push(createData(i, scoops[i]?.rank, scoops[i]?.title, scoops[i]?.url));
  }

  return <Base rows={rows} duration="Week" />;
}
```

Here is the server terminal log:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 08, 2021 - 10:59:59
Django version 3.2.8, using settings 'app.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.4 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
HTTP GET /week/ 200 [0.02, 127.0.0.1:62685]
HTTP GET /api/scoops/week/ 200 [0.14, 127.0.0.1:62685]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/week/ [127.0.0.1:62695]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/week/ [127.0.0.1:62695]
```

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems the socket connect is failed somehow, try to add error handler `socket.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
  console.log('WebSocket error: ', event);
});` to see more information.

Comment: This is the error message I get after adding the eventListener
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y3mc88uUZI1GctDFuY9juc4QIOm-8Ogo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems to me that server code has some problem, it didn't accept the client connect.

Comment: I wrote a very simple consumer.py to get started, do you think this could be causing the issue?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10lpelDA3vZ0sTjnnWFjYnXB8Q7qcMbs-/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was a result of my server code not accepting the connection from the frontend. Adding the following code to consumers.py fixed the issue:

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
```

Also made changes to routing.py which looks like this now:

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"ws/week/", consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```