# Websockets, React + Django

Tags: reactjs, django, websocket

I'm curious if there's a definitive answer on using Websockets, React and Django.

From what I've read (1) the preferred way to link React with Django is to use Django Rest Framework (DRF.) (2) The preferred way to leverage websockets in Django, it would seem is through Django Channels. (3) And the preferred way to use websockets in React is through Socket.io.

So it seems that linking all three is rather difficult. I see two possible solutions, which neither might be valid.

1. React uses Socket.io and passes communicates w/ the backend via DRF.
2. React is rendered through a Django template and websockets are leveraged via Channels.

I imagine that #2 is the path with more headaches as Django is very opinionated framework.

Is there a definitive answer on how Websockets, React and Django should be used together? ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70270627/react-django-websocket-connection-challenge) got virtually no traction.)

Edit Less preferred option 3: Use React, Node & Express for most of the application, including websockets and DRF solely for the things that python really shines (ex ML pipelines.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no definitive answer (and I think shouldnt be) on using websockets, React and Django. Those are different technologies although they can be nicely connected. It is up to you how you connect them. The best approach is to use them to achieve your project requirements with the simplest overall architecture.

Sometime ago I created an example project that was using:

- Django for backend (Django Rest Framework, Django Channels and Celery),
- React for frontend (communicating with REST API and WebSockets with [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws))

The project is available on the GitHub: https://github.com/pplonski/simple-tasks

The project was deployed with `docker-compose` ([docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/pplonski/simple-tasks/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file) and have following components:

- nginx serving React
- wsgiserver serving REST API
- asgiserver serving websocekts
- rabbitmq & redis for Celery
- worker & listeners for Celery

The project was doing simple sum of two numbers and sleep. The task was computed in the background with Celery and I was using websockets to live communication about progress (every 1 second of sleeping the update was send to the client).

The React+Django is my preferred stack because I work on many Data Science/Machine Learning projects.

Comment: your project looks great but would you have any documentation appart from what is available on github ? a bit difficult to untangle.

Comment: I created a paid tutorial with step-by-step instructions on how to build a web service with React and Django. It is available on https://SaaSitive.com, but it is not using WebSockets - just Django+Celery for tasks processing

Comment: Why do you have a ASGI and WSGI server (daphne and Gunicorn) while you could handle the http part with Daphne ? trying to understand.

Comment: @pam - I dont remember why I did like that ... sorry

Comment: its ok - it is still probably the best ressource to implement websocket for django + react . thank you